# Replacing Outlet with Switch Middle of Run

Tags: electrical

Trying to wire unfinished basement with new can lights.

There's an outlet mid height on wall at bottom of stairs that also powers a number of lights downstream that would be ideal location for switch for these new lights.

I want to replace the outlet with Lutron Caseta switch and simply run new 14/2 to the first can and so on down the line.  The switch only has two black wires...so one will go to pigtail hot and the other to the first light.

**Is there a way to do this without the new switch affecting all the downstream lights/outlets?**

Originally I was thinking switch loop but this layout would be simpler and no white wire serving as a conductor.  Just don't know if it makes sense.

Thanks for your assistance!

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 4):

This will work fine. Switch loops are for when the power comes in at the fixture, its not applicable here. 
One word of caution, you can't just go around removing outlets, the old 6 foot rule. You could install a two gang box and keep the outlet there or just install another one right below the exiting one, easy to just drop down the /2 cable.

Comment: Awesome!  There’s an outlet two feet away to the right so I’m in good shape.  Thank you

Comment: You didn't show the ground wires but you need to route them too.

Comment: Of course, thanks Jack

Comment: It will work but the OP may not understand the 6’ rule that in a finished room no wall space will be more than 6’ from an outlet or 12’ spacing max. There are other parts but that is the basic rule.

Comment: @EdBeal  I wanted to give you something to do...  +